# How to copy-paste a picture from one ppt to another ppt

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have 2 sets of ppt. The first set is a template which contains a placeholder shape on slide 1. The other ppt contains an image on slide 1 which I would like to copy and replace it with the placeholder in the first ppt.

When I run the following code mentioned below I get this error msg

> Compiled error: Method or data member not found

**Code:**

```
Sub copySlide()
Dim objPresentation As Presentation

Set objPresentation = Presentations.Open("/path/slides.ppt")

objPresentation.Slides.Item(1).Shapes("image_1").Copy
Presentations.Item(1).Slides.Shapes("image_placeholder_1").Paste

objPresentation.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to specify a Slide in the Paste part and then tune the placement of the picture :

```
Sub copySlide()
    Dim objPresentation As Presentation
    Set objPresentation = Presentations.Open("/path/slides.ppt")
    Dim PPShape As Object

    objPresentation.Slides.Item(1).Shapes("image_1").Copy
    Set PPShape = Presentations.Item(1).Slides(1).Shapes.Paste

With PPShape
    .Height = 100
    'Place from bottom using : PPPres.PageSetup.SlideHeigth - .Height
    .Top = PPPres.PageSetup.SlideHeigth - .Height - 10
    .Width = 100
    'Place from right using : PPPres.PageSetup.SlideWidth - .Width
    .Left = PPPres.PageSetup.SlideWidth - .Width - 10
End With

    objPresentation.Close
End Sub
```